# Get Web Response Status Code properly Asynchronously

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, http, httpresponse

I'm searching for a solution in **C#** or else **VB.Net** for this problem.

Using a `WebClient` I would like to retrieve the server response of `UploadValuesAsync` method  asynchronously but I can't figure it out how to do it.

Basically I want to do the same done in this question, get the response code as Integer (but asynchronouslly): [Get Web Response Status Code properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28025976/get-web-response-status-code-properly)

Example code:

The problem with the code below is the same problem exposed in the other question that I linked, it throws an exception if the `e.result` property is not ok then I can't parse any other status code than a **200** code because that exception.

I've searched for a `Response` property on the `e.Error` exception but I didn't found anything, so I'm not able to proceed.

```vb
AddHandler wc.UploadValuesCompleted, AddressOf WC_UploadValuesCompleted
wc.UploadValuesAsync(New Uri("https://api.imgur.com/3/upload.xml"), values)
```

Then:

```vb
Private Sub WC_UploadValuesCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As UploadValuesCompletedEventArgs)

   If Not e.Cancelled Then

        Dim responseAsync As Byte() = e.Result

        ' Read the response (Converting Byte-Array to Stream).
        Using sr As New StreamReader(New MemoryStream(responseAsync))

            Dim serverResponse As String = sr.ReadToEnd
            Dim xdoc As New XDocument(XDocument.Parse(serverResponse))
            Dim status As ImgurStatus = Nothing

            status = Me.GetResultFromStatus(Convert.ToInt32(xdoc.Root.LastAttribute.Value.ToString))

            Select Case status

                Case ImgurStatus.Success ' 200
                    Return New ImgurImage(New Uri(xdoc.Descendants("link").Value))

                Case ImgurStatus.AccessForbidden ' 403
                    RaiseEvent OnAccessForbidden(Me, ImgurStatus.AccessForbidden)

                Case ImgurStatus.AuthorizationFailed ' 401
                    RaiseEvent OnAuthorizationFailed(Me, ImgurStatus.AuthorizationFailed)

                Case ImgurStatus.BadImageFormat ' 400
                    RaiseEvent OnBadImageFormat(Me, ImgurStatus.BadImageFormat)

                Case ImgurStatus.InternalServerError ' 500
                    RaiseEvent OnInternalServerError(Me, ImgurStatus.InternalServerError)

                Case ImgurStatus.PageIsNotFound ' 404
                    RaiseEvent OnPageIsNotFound(Me, ImgurStatus.PageIsNotFound)

                Case ImgurStatus.UploadRateLimitError ' 429
                    RaiseEvent OnUploadRateLimitError(Me, ImgurStatus.UploadRateLimitError)

                Case ImgurStatus.UnknownError ' -0
                    RaiseEvent OnUnknownError(Me, ImgurStatus.UnknownError)
                    Return Nothing

            End Select

        End Using '/ sr As New StreamReader

   End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `HttpClient` class has very nice methods to do it asynchronously.

Comment: Thanks for comment, but I don't know how to.

Comment: dont try and pass the exception result as an event arg.  parse it on the spot and convert to a result *value*.  the (original) `RequestToken` method already has code doing just that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code worked for me (using [Json.Net](https://json.codeplex.com/)):

```
async private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var response = await UploadToImgUrl(filename, client_id);
}
```

---

```
async Task<ImgUrl.Response> UploadToImgUrl(string fname, string client_id)
{
    string endPoint = "https://api.imgur.com/3/upload";
    var data = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(fname));

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "Client-ID " + client_id);    
        var resp = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(endPoint, new { image = data, type= "base64", name = new FileInfo(fname).Name });
        var content  = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ImgUrl.Response>(content);
    }
}

public class ImgUrl
{
    public class Data
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int Datetime { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public bool Animated { get; set; }
        public int Width { get; set; }
        public int Height { get; set; }
        public int Size { get; set; }
        public int Views { get; set; }
        public int Bandwidth { get; set; }
        public string Deletehash { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Link { get; set; }
    }

    public class Response
    {
        public Data Data { get; set; }
        public bool Success { get; set; }
        public int Status { get; set; }
    }
}
```